# How to get and identify POST formdata with PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, methods

I'm trying to process some data from a form with a PHP file but I don't know what's the data name or their values because it is created dynamically.

So, the formdata is sent to my PHP file with POST Method. How can I get all the keys and its values? I need to get $_POST[key]=value for all that I receive.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I tried this:

```
 foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
      echo($key.' > '.$value.'<br />');
  mail('nlopez@edge-americas.com', 'form', $key=>$value);
 }
```

but I received this by email:

purga_url > Array

'purga_url' is the key but 'Array' isn't the value.

Why is this happening? How do I get the value?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST, array_keys($_POST));`

Comment: please avoid giving answers to quesions which are already asked in SO

Comment: @Ashish Just because two questions have the same answer, that doesn't make them the same question.  If you really can find the exact same question (and I couldn't in two minutes), you should mark this as a duplicate of it, not complain to us that we are answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, you can iterate through the post values,

To see the all the post values use this.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

or you can iterate the post value.

```
$post_key = array_keys($_POST);

foreach($post_key as $key){

 echo $key .'='. $_POST[$key];

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is really very basic:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    // do stuff with each one
}
```

EDIT:

Getting them into emails:

```
$emailing = '';
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $emailing .= $key.': ';
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $emailing .= implode(', ',$value);  //use implode to quickly turn arrays to strings
    } else {
        $emailing .= $value;
    }
    $emailing .= "\r\n\r\n";    //two line breaks (one = \r\n) between values
}
//you don't have to echo this, but if you want to, use <br /> for line breaks
echo str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $emailing);

//sending the email
mail('nlopez@edge-americas.com', 'form', $emailing);
```

Note that mail() takes exactly one string.  You don't ever say something like `$key=>$value` in that spot.

Comment: I tried this, and also sending me the values by email inside the loop but I only received: purga_url > Array

When 'purga_url' is the key but Array isn't its value. Why does it happen?

Comment: If you have an array of values, and you try to put them into something that takes a single value, it will represent that array with the word "Array."  I will edit my post to show you what to do.